# Executing an sql script vi an OCI8 connection object

Tags: ruby, oracle, oci8

I have a locally running oracle thin client and have successfully created a ruby script to connect to a remote oracle database. I successfully make a call (select * from table_name) to the database to get the content of a table:

```
begin  
    con = OCI8.new('<user>', <password>, '<host>:<port>/XE')  
    con.exec('select name from actor') do |records|
        puts records
    end
rescue OCIError
  puts "Database Connection Error"
end
```

I also want to run an sql script that resides in the oracle directory on the remote host.
Usually I perform the following:

```
su - oracle
sqlplus <user>/<password>
<SQL> @<script_name>
```

and this will run the script

In the ruby script I try the following:

```
con.exec('@<script_name>')
```

Yet, I get the following error:

```
stmt.c:230:in oci8lib_200.bundle: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (OCIError)
```

Answer (score 1):

`@<script_name>` is an sqlplus command.
When sqlplus find `@<script_name>`, it opens `<script_name>`, divides its contents to SQL statements and executes them.
If you want to run SQL statements in a script by ruby, you need to write code which opens the script, divides its contents and pass SQL statements to `con.exec` one by one.

> I also want to run an sql script that resides in the oracle directory on the remote host. Usually I perform the following:

No, it can't. sqlplus reads the sql script that resides on the local host.

Comment: Thanks @Albert. In the meantime I changed the gem to connect to my instance. Right now I'm using net-ssh ruby gem. And i run the following command: ssh.exec!("su - oracle -c 'sqlplus <user>/<password>' <<EOF\n#{<command>}\nEOF\n")

Answer (score 0):

You can put this script in a function (*function_name*) and execute

```
con.exec("select function_name from dual")
```